# React Navigation Drawer not responding to gestures or menu button in iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

I am quite new to React Native and I was trying to configure a new project. I have integrated the React Navigation library in the project following the official documentation here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/. To my surprise, the drawer is working as expected if I make it permanent (always visible). Please check the below video for reference:

[image]

This is the piece of code that makes it work:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import  Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import  Bookings from './Bookings';
import  Store from './Store';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        drawerType: Dimensions.get('window').width >= 768 ? 'permanent' : 'front',
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Add/Modify Store(s)" component={Store} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Bookings" component={Bookings} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}


class Home extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <MyDrawer />
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
  }

export default Home;
```

But when I want to keep the drawer hidden by default and only open if the user taps on the hamburger button on top left or drags their finger from left to right. It does not respond to the tap on the hamburger button or the gesture.

This is the code that I should use according to the documents:

```
function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Add/Modify Store(s)" component={Store} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Bookings" component={Bookings} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Here is the resulting video:

[image]

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.190.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-flipper": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.9",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong and what is the remedy.